# JQuery added form elements not being posted in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have read all the posts related to this topic but none of them seems to work for me.

Here is my code for the dynamic form elements:

```
<input type="text" name="nItemID[]" id="iItemID" value="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>" class="SN" readonly />

<input type="text" name="nFK_ICS[]" id="iFK_ICS" value="<?php echo $icsID; >" class="SN" readonly />
```

And here is jquery for the append:

```
$('#iICS').append(itemdata);
```

The code of the main page that contains the main form looks like this:

```
<form>
  <div id="main">
    //some elements here
  </div>

  <div id="iICS">
    //append the dynamic elements here
  </div>

</form>
```

Thank you very much in advance. I hope this will get done soon with your help.

Note: I have tried to append it to the form itself but it doesn't work as well. And the form elements are displayed as expected.

Comment: `<input type="text" name="nFK_ICS[]" id="iFK_ICS" value="<?php echo $icsID; ?>" class="SN" readonly />` Close the PHP properly

Comment: it seems the problem is within my query. And I can't figure for the life of me what's wrong with this: $insert_query = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO ICS_ITEM (FK_ICS_MAIN,INVENTORY_NUM,USEFUL_LIFE) VALUES".implode(',', $row_data));

Comment: can you edit your question and put the query with the data that goes into the `values`

Comment: Thank you guys for your time but I have finally found the problem and got it fixed. Thank you very much.